# Alternatives to setInterval?

Tags: javascript, function

I just wanted to ask if there are any methods out there like `setInterval()` that can be paused so another command can take place. I'm coding a traffic light system and each image comes up on the screen(these are the lights) and stays on for different amounts of time, that is why I cant use `setInterval()` or `setTimeout` because it plays in a sequence.

Comment: Just use a recursive approach with `setTimeout`.

Comment: You could use a loop instead. A bit more work but timers are just fancy loops.

Comment: You can't pause the execution of a function nor can you abort a currently running one. And as of that you can't resume a given function. What you could to is to create a array of functions that should be executed in sequence, allow other tasks to take place after each of them.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a variable to control the behavior of the interval function.

```
var enabled = true;
setInterval(function() {
    if (!enabled) {
        return;
    }
    // rest of code here
}, period);
```

Then some other code can set `enabled` to `false` and the interval function will effectively be paused.